Добавление метки на выбранной дате в Aiogram_calendar
Такой вопрос. Начал использовать библиотеку Aiogram_calendar для своего бота. Бот будет использоваться как хранилище задач. Например,пользователь выбирает дату на inline календаре, далее пишет задачу и сохраняет ее. Есть кнопка Показать календарь. Нажав на нее, я хочу видеть Inline календарь с метками, означающими,что на данное число есть какая-то задача,например, такую "". Как это можно осуществить?
